# How to add some additional info to a message in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to be able to send different kinds of messages to RabbitMQ so that as a **consumer I can distinguish** them. I don't want to add anything to the bodies of the messages. How can I do that?

```
  # producer
  channel1.basic_publish(exchange="", routing_key="something", body="fdsfds")  # something here maybe?
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using headers ? It is useful to add meta-informations to the message!

Just as follows : https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/pika-python/LjCldaIhEzA

Comment: is that the only way?